# Stokes' theorem on a paraboloid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, parametrization, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I am currently undertaking a class on Classical Electrodynamics, and I am realising my multivariable calculus skills are slightly rusty, as it has been a few years.

Anyhow, I am given a surface
$$S\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|z=1-x^2-y^2, z>0\}$$
and a vector field
$$\textbf{F}(x,y,z)=(z,x,y)$$
Which I am then tasked to sketch the surface (which is fair enough, it is obviously a paraboloid with a global maximum at $z=1$)

I am then to verify Stokes' theorem by computing both the right and left-hand sides of it manually, and compare, i.e. to compute and compare
$$\oint_{\partial C}\textbf{F}\cdot \textrm{d}\textrm{S} \ \ \ \ \textrm{and} \ \ \ \  \iint_{C}(\nabla \times \textbf{F})\cdot \textrm{d}\textbf{S}$$ where $\partial C$ is the boundary of $C$

So anyway, I go about my business and parameterize the curve
$$\textbf{r}(\theta)=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0), \ \ \ 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$$
as it is the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ projected down into the $xy$-plane. By extension we then have $$\int_{\partial C}\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(\theta))\cdot\textbf{r}'(\theta)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2(\theta)=\pi $$

Now when I go to compute the right hand side I start by parameterizing the surface as

$$\textbf{A}(r,\theta)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),1-r^2), \ \ \ 0\leq \theta\leq2\pi, \ \ \ 0\leq r\leq 1$$

To compute the integral I need my $\textrm{d}\textbf{S}$, which I compute by utilizing the fundamental vector product, i.e.
$$\textrm{d}\textbf{S}=\frac{\partial\textbf{A}}{\partial{r}}\times \frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial\theta }=(2r^2\cos\theta,2r^2\sin\theta,r)$$
Using Curl in Cylindrical coordinates we find
$$\nabla \times \textbf{F}=\nabla\times(z,x,y)=\nabla\times(z=1-r^2,r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=(\cos(\theta),-\sin(\theta),2\cos(\theta))$$

Edit: For some further clarification on the curl I used that
$$\nabla \times \textbf{F}=\hat{\textbf{r}}\left(\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta F_z-\partial_zF_\theta\right)+\hat{\theta}\left(\partial_zF_r-\partial_rF_z\right)+\hat{\textbf{z}}\left(\frac{1}{r}\partial_r rF_\theta-\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta F_r\right)$$
I first tried it with a parameterized $z=1-r^2$ which yielded the above answer, then I tried it with $z$ for the heck of it and it's identical with the only difference being the $\phi$-component being $1-\sin(\theta)$

When the first try is dotted with $\textrm{d}\textbf{S}$ it gives
$$(\nabla\times\textbf{F})\cdot \textrm{d}\textbf{S}=2r^2\cos(2\theta)+2r\cos(\theta)$$

When the second try is dotted with $\textrm{d}\textbf{S}$ it gives
$$-2r^2\sin^2(\theta)-2r\sin(\theta)+2r^2\cos^2(\theta)+2r\cos(\theta)=2r^2\cos(2\theta)+2r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)$$

But when I integrate that entire shebang (well both of them) over $0$ to 2$\pi$ and $0$ to $1$ (I now realised $rdrd\theta$ was baked into dS ) it spits out zero which is not equal to one, so I am at a loss of where it is I am failing. If someone could help a poor soul out, that would be nice.

Comment: Too many confusing things here. First, the $r$ in $r\,dr\,d\theta$ is already built into your $d\mathbf S$ calculation, but when you write $d\mathbf S$ you need the $dr\,d\theta$ following the vector. Second, you have to compute the curl in $xyz$-coordinates and *then* plug in the parametrization. The curl is $(1,1,1)$, is it not?

Comment: Wouldn't $\nabla \times (z,x,y)=(0,0,0)$? Edit: Nevermind I am stupid, I computed the Curl of (z,y,x)

Comment: Yeah, apparently the curl is where I went wrong as I now arrived at the right answer. That begs the question, why can I not take the curl in cylindrical coordinates directly, i.e. why do I have to compute the curl in cartesian coordinates, do you have any insight? @TedShifrin

Comment: Well, there are (non-obvious) formulas for gradient, curl, and divergence in polar, cylindrical, spherical (and so on) coordinates, but then you need everything in terms of $\hat r,\hat\theta,\hat z$ coordinates.

Comment: I did take the curl in cylidrincal coordinates though, that's why it is so weird to me that it didn't work out.

Comment: If you share your reasoning/calculations for the curl, then we can clarify your mistake/misunderstanding

Comment: @MarkS. I completed the task and it worked out, but I have editted my post to include calculations of the curl, because I sure would like to know where it is I am failing with cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: The issue is that
$$z \boldsymbol i + x \boldsymbol j + y \boldsymbol k \neq
z \hat {\boldsymbol e}_r + r \cos(\phi) \hat {\boldsymbol e}_\phi +
 r \sin(\phi) \hat {\boldsymbol e}_z,$$
a field with components $(f, g, h)$ in Cartesian coordinates becomes
$$(g \sin \phi + f \cos \phi) \hat {\boldsymbol e}_r +
 (g \cos \phi - f \sin \phi) \hat {\boldsymbol e}_\phi +
 h \hat {\boldsymbol e}_z$$
in the local basis associated with cylindrical coordinates.